# How can I change blogger posts font size

Tags: html, css, post, blogger

I'm trying to change the font size in my posts on blogger https://dogsinfotag.blogspot.com/ and I'm not having any luck finding the body/post font size in the html section to change it. I was able to change my header menu links and sidebar title sizes with no problem, but the actual blog posts are giving me trouble. I don't know what to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Theme -> Costumize -> Advanced and then search the posts options. Read for more info: https://techsmp.blogspot.com/2020/03/Customize-Blogger-Theme.html

Comment: @osvaldo-correia Already tried it but still the same problem, thx anyway

Comment: When use the inspect option to figure out the code ( body-post font size ) so that to customize it in my HTML. In other words, I find my self not allowed to copy the code  to change it and told it's (inherited from body)  : @Community

Comment: I visited your blog and went to the single blog posts. 2 things I noticed: 1. to edit the size of your blog post in the html look for .item-post .post-body and 2. you probably use any editor to write your posts that add a lot of unnecessary spans to the post. One of them adds a font-size: medium. My advice is to go into the tab HTML in the post editor and clean that extra spans... or at least, the ones that are screwing your font size.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to find the code for adjusting the font size, it's easy,

you just need to select one paragraph or sentence in your post, then right click and select inspect element, when inspect opens the code that adjusts the font size in that paragraph can be seen in the style.

after that you just need to look for it in the blogger html edit section and replace it. if you are still confused or need a visual example you can read it in this article [How to change the entire font size in blogger articles](https://mmtipsdantrik.blogspot.com/2021/11/how-to-change-entire-font-size-in-blogger.html)